Is there a rule about when to use non-comma punctuation in lyrics for choral works?
In the realm of classical-style choral music, is there a rule for when to use punctuation marks other than the comma in the lyrics which appear directly under the staff?  (I understand the conventional use of commas to indicate breaks in phrase/breathing for singers.)
Here is my wonder.
Imagine a work with several different texts in one movement.  It is better to use only commas for the end of each phrase until the very end of the movement, and then use a period for the last word?  What about separate texts in the same work?  Commas only, or period at the end of each separate text?
Relatedly, are exclamation points/question marks ever appropriate?  These sometimes appear in text but don't have a clearly-defined musical meaning.

The traditional use of commas in lyrics is to delineate text repetition (as in "music, music for a while shall all your cares beguile, shall all, all, all, all, ... [etc.]) and where a comma is called for by the usual rules of punctuation.  In general, therefore, you can in most cases survive with this rule:

Punctuate the text as it is (or would be) written independently, but add a comma everywhere you repeat text (or, if there is another punctuation mark at that point, change it to a comma).  If the repetition occurs at the end of a musical and textual phrase, use your judgment as to whether to use a comma or the original punctuation mark.

If you're mixing and matching separate texts, you can use periods (or question marks or exclamation points as appropriate) between the various sections.
Most singers (and many choral conductors) don't pay a lot of attention to these details of punctuation, which is why there are so many misconceptions about them.  One of the most prevalent misconceptions is that a comma in the text must be reflected in the musical phrasing.  This is a dangerous idea that spoils a lot of performances, and many people disagree with it fairly strongly.  In short, a comma in the text does not have a clearly defined musical meaning; the idea that it does is a matter of controversy.
If you want singers to make a musical phrase break, you should put the comma above the staff, not necessarily in the lyrics, or use some other phrase mark such as a slur.  But mostly you should just trust them to be good at singing texts well.

A couple of points relating to the dangers of observing textual commas as musical expression marks:

many people attempt to apply the practice to texts that didn't have any punctuation in the original sources, where the commas were added by editors.  In other words, the commas really are not part of the music that the composer wrote.

punctuation rules differ in different languages, notably in German, and commas often have a structural function that isn't necessarily reflected in speech.  For example, in (modern) German you have to separate a subordinate clause with a comma, but people don't necessarily pause at that point when speaking.



While other punctuation marks don't usually have a direct musical meaning, they have a clear linguistic meaning — and that can (and usually should) affect how you sing them.
Yes, singers are sometimes guilty of treating words merely as sounds to make — it's easy to do, but in most cases it's to the detriment of the song.  A song can be so much more moving, interesting, inspiring, or simply engaging if the words are made to mean something.  Some songs tell stories; some project emotion; some engage us in moral questions, or incite us to action, or inspire us to be better people; and none of those reach their full potential unless the singer makes something of the words.
Yes, there are songs whose main point is simply to sound beautiful, and would be spoiled by an overly dramatic or emotional performance.  In those cases, the voice is best treated as an instrument, and the meaning neglected.  But I think those are uncommon, at least in more traditional forms of music; they could simply have been written as wordless songs or instrumentals instead.  If meaningful words have been written, there's usually a reason for them, and so the writer intended them to be used to the full.
Since punctuation is part of that meaning, it goes along with the words as an integral part of the song.
